# JPA orphan removal does not work for OneToOne relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9663?

I am also facing a similar issue. When I created one-sided (no reverse reference) one to one relationship between two entities and set the orphan removal attribute to true, the referenced object is still in the database after setting the reference to null.

Here is the sample domain model:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
  ...
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "child_id")
  private Child child;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Child {
  ...
  @Lob
   private byte[] data;
  ...
}
```

I am currently working around this by manually deleting orphans.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Cascading only makes sense for entity state transitions that propagate from a *Parent* to a *Child*. In your case, the Parent was actually the child of this association (having the FK).

Try with this mapping instead:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
  ...
  @OneToOne(
      fetch = FetchType.LAZY, 
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
      orphanRemoval = true, 
      mappedBy = "parent"
  )
  private Child child;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class Child {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private Parent parent;

    ...
    @Lob
    private byte[] data;
    ...
}
```

And to cascade the orphan removal, you now need to:

```
Parent parent = ...;
parent.getChild().setParent(null);
parent.setChild(null);
```

Or even better, confgiure the `setChild` method in the `Parent` entity class to set both associations:

```
public void setChild(Child child) {
    if (child == null) {
        if (this.child != null) {
            this.child.setParent(null);
        }
    }
    else {
        child.setParent(this);
    }
    this.child = child;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it is working as you described but for some reason my lazy loading has stopped working now. I looked at the query generated and I can see two select calls happening one for getting the parent and other for child and parent joined. Any ideas?

Comment: Two selects means the LAZY works. You can JOIN FETCH using an HQL/JPQL query.

Comment: I meant when I do something like - Parent result = repository.findOne(parent.getId()). I see two selects. I was think only when I do something like: result.getChild() - I would see the second select. Is that not a right assumption?

Comment: It is because Hibernate cannot know if the association is null or not so it needs a second query. To avoid it you need to specify optional=true if the FK is NOT NULL. Otherwise you need to use lazy initialization with bytecode enhancement.

Comment: You mean - "optional=false"? I have added:

@OneToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Parent parent;

Comment: parent.getChild().setParent(null) does not seem to be necessary to propagate the removal, at least not with hibernate.

Comment: "parent.getChild().setParent(null) does not seem to be necessary to propagate the removal, at least not with hibernate." - Surely it should not be, the "parent" property may even be non-nullable, right?

Comment: Even if it works on the version of Hibernate you tested, it's never guaranteed to work in a future release unless you synchronize both sides of the association.

Comment: @VladMihalcea There is not `children` field in the `Parent` class.