# Hibernate delete orphan on replacing OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Team extends EntityBase {
    ...... 

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            orphanRemoval = true, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "auth_id")
    private TeamAuthentication auth;

   ......

}
```

so it has a `TeamAuthentication` table reference. The latter entity looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class TeamAuthentication {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String accessToken;

}
```

What I want is that when I fetch existing `Team` entity from the table and replace a reference to `TeamAuthentication` table there for field `auth`, then persist this `Team` entity with `teamRepository.save()`, I want that old `TeamAuthentication` would be deleted from its table. At the moment it stays in the table and becomes sort of a loitering entry that won't be ever used or queried.

How can I leverage Hibernate cascade in deleting OneToOne reference on change?

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.x verison

Comment: Could you say exact version?

Comment: yes, sorry. It's `Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}`

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470414/orphan-removal-does-not-work-for-onetoone-relations

Comment: The easiest way for you to fix it would be to set fetch = FetchType.EAGER

Comment: I checked your link. Thanks for posting it. I think this is a bit too extreme to add another foreign key column to a table just to be able to leverage cascade deletion :(

Comment: Maybe you're right. Did you try FetchType.EAGER?