# Child object is not deleted

Tags: java, eclipselink, jpql

I have problem with cascade deleting of child object. I use EclipseLink. 
Mapping of One-to-One relationships when primary key in the parent table is also a primary key in the child table.

```
 class Parent {
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Child child;

}

class Child {
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", unique = true)
    private Parent childId;
}
```

When I try "DELETE FROM Parent parent WHERE parent.id in :parentIds" I get info that child object was found. Could you give me some advise please?

Answer (score 2):

This problem usually occurs in OneToOne type of mapping, due to Foreign key constraint from Parent to Child, Since Child Entity would point to a nonexisting entity. You have to first get rid of the references, by finding the entity and its mapping, setting null the references and then you can merge/persist/delete it.

A similar question is asked here, Please take a help from here:
[JPA orphan removal does not work for OneToOne relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470414/jpa-orphan-removal-does-not-work-for-onetoone-relations)

Answer (score 1):

JPQL bulk updates and deletes don't load object into memory, so you are responsible for removing or fixing any references yourself. In this case, you need to run a bulk delete to clear the children before you can remove the parents.