# Spring Data JPA: Deleting a parent entity, children are not being removed

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

My entities.
ValidationStep has a one to one relationship with documentDetail and documentDetail has a oneToMany relationship of documentValidations

ValidationStep

```
@Entity
public class ValidationStep {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name= "automation_information_aId", referencedColumnName= "aId")
private AutomationInformation automationInformation;

@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private DocumentDetail documentDetail;
 }
```

DocumentDetail

```
@Entity
public class DocumentDetail {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "documentDetail_id")
private List<DocumentValidation> documentValidationList
```

DocumentValidation

```
@Entity
public class DocumentValidation implements Comparable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


}
```

My delete query

```
        @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM ValidationStep validationStep WHERE validationStep.automationInformation.id = :aId AND isDraft is true")
    void  deleteAllDraftsByAutomationInformationaID(@Param("aId") Long aId);
```

The parent ValidationStep is removed, however the docDetail and documentValidations are still in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA orphan removal does not work for OneToOne relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470414/jpa-orphan-removal-does-not-work-for-onetoone-relations)

Answer (score 1):

From the JPA specifications (paragraph 4.10: Bulk Update and Delete Operations
):

> A delete operation only applies to entities of the specified class and its subclasses. It does not cascade to related entities.

The remove cascade only works if you execute use `EntityManager.remove()` to delete your entity. Not if you execute a delete query.

Comment: Yeah I am using CrudRepository. So I first retrieved the Entites by the id I wanted to delete, then used repo.deleteAll(entity collection)