# How to remove a user and the refresh tokens that are referencing it?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, one-to-one, refresh-token

I have two models (User and RefreshToken). when I try to remove a user by an API, I get this error:

> (id)=(5) is still referenced from table "refreshtoken"

This is my `User` model:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "users", 
    uniqueConstraints = { 
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email") 
    })
    public class User implements Serializable {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @NotBlank
        @Size(max = 20)
        private String username;

        @NotBlank
        @Size(max = 50)
        @Email
        private String email;

        @NotBlank
        @Size(max = 120)
        private String password;

        @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable( name = "user_roles", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
        private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

And this is my `refreshToken` model:

```
@Entity(name = "refreshtoken")
public class RefreshToken {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String token;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant expiryDate;

    //getters and setters
```

When I want to delete a user I want the refresh tokens that belong to that user also be removed in database. I searched and I found I should use cascade or orphanRemoval but I didn't understand how to use them here.

I would be very appreciated if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1):

Do a bi-directional relationship by adding the `RefreshToken` in the user and use `CascadeType.ALL`.

Example:

```java
@Entity
@Table( name = "users", 
    uniqueConstraints = { 
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "username"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email") 
    })
    public class User implements Serializable {
        ....
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
        private RefreshToken refreshToken;
        ....
   }
```

And in the `RefreshToken` Entity :

```java
@Entity(name = "refreshtoken")
public class RefreshToken {
   
        ....
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private User user;
        ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `@OneToOne` association from User to `RefreshToken`.

```java
@Entity
class User {

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private RefreshToken token;

}

@Entity
class RefreshToken {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

}
```

Read this for ways of deleting a token with a user:
[JPA orphan removal does not work for OneToOne relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470414/jpa-orphan-removal-does-not-work-for-onetoone-relations)

Keep in mind that you can model one-to-one association using `@ManyToOne` on the user side (so you will have FK on the user side, not on the token side). Probably you will want to add an unique constraint for the token FK in the users table.

You can use `@OneToOne` with a `@JoinColumn` on the user side as well. So there will not be a User FK in the token.

Use `Long id` in place of `long id` in the `RefreshToken`.

Answer (score 1):

to use the cascade option, you should update the user class by adding a RefreshToken so when a user was deleted the operation can be cascaded to RefreshToken.

```
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private RefreshToken refreshToken = RefreshToken;
```

This way when a user was deleted the RefreshToken related to him will be deleted as well.