# Implement "reverse" orphan removal with JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have an entity Address that is referenced by several other entities, for example:

```
@Entity
class Office {
    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

    ...
}

@Entity
class Home {
    @OneToOne
    private Address address;

    ...
}
```

where

```
@Entity
class Address {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String street;
    private String zipCode;
    
    ...
}
```

The field referencing `Address` in the other entities is nullable, so I'd like that when, for example, `Office.address` is set to `null`, the referenced entity is removed from database.

This is similar to how `orphanRemoval` works, but in my situation I need that the *parent* class (`Address`) instance is removed, instead of the *child*.

Is there a way to achieve this using a declarative way, or shoul I manually remove the unreferenced `Address`es?

**NOTES**

- a new address is created every time a new Office/Home/etc. is created. (There are no shared addresses referenced by other entities.)
- I tried to apply orphanRemoval to `@OneToOne` annotation, but setting the `address` field to null doesn't trigger the (`Address`) entity to be removed from the database.
- I already checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31471415/1061499, but this is not applicable to my case. I can't include a cross reference in my `Address` class.

Comment: You are using the same address in Home and Office? If yes then it's a ManyToOne and not a OneToOne. If not then you can use orphan removal

Comment: @SimonMartinelli no, not the same: a new address is created every time a new Office/Home is created. I tried to apply orphanRemoval to OneToOne, but setting the address field to null doesn't trigger the (address) entity to be removed from the database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA orphan removal does not work for OneToOne relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31470414/jpa-orphan-removal-does-not-work-for-onetoone-relations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replicating your problem as follows, `orphanRemoval` works as expected:
https://github.com/fladdimir/so-jpa/blob/b324b3d2867ba62ee3e96357822ea9aee86a10a0/src/test/java/org/demo/address/AddressTest.java#L57

```
@Entity
@Data
class Home {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true) // should work as shown in the linked test
  private Address address; // <- associated entity is removed when set to 'null'
}
```

Does this work for you? If not, what are the differences to your setup?

Comment: yes, you're right. Probably there was some issue in my code. Thank you very much!